# SSLHandshakeException: The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]-Karate API Automation

Tags: java, ssl, soap, automation, karate

I'm trying an api automation using karate and I'm getting below error,

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]

Java: jdk-16.0.1
karate: 0.9.6

`Background:
* url 'https://xxxx:xxxx'
* header Content-Type = 'application/soap; charset=utf-8'
* configure ssl = true
* configure readTimeout = 240000
* configure connectTimeout = 240000

Scenario: post a request
* path '/xxxx'
* xmlstring requestXml = read('request.xml')
* request requestXml
* method post
* status 200
* print response`

Comment: Oh it very well can be a bug no one has seen yet. Please follow this process (exactly as described): https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue Else there is nothing much anyone can do, and you need to do research and figure this out on your own.